# Передать значение переменной через форму

Tags: php, php7

Нужно передать значение `$event_id`

Запрос в базу данных:

```
$event_info = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT event_id, title, event_date FROM Event");
$event_info_json = json_decode(json_encode($event_info), true);
```

Массив с мероприятиями из таблицы Event

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 3889
            [title] => ISTAS
            [event_date] => 21.12.2022
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 3991
            [title] => Шоу Трансформеров на планете пузырей
            [event_date] => 3.12.2022
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 3993
            [title] => Супершоу кукол ЛОЛ
            [event_date] => 3.12.2022
        )
)
```

Пытался разложить массив так:

```
foreach ($event_info_json as $row) {
  $dayCouwfnts[$row['event_id']] = $row['title'];
}
```

Сама форма:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Выберите мероприетие:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <?php 
        foreach ( $dayCouwfnts as $key => $value) {
            echo '<option name="' . $key . '"> Тут должно быть название и дата мероприятия </option>';
        } 
      ?> 
    </select>
    <button>OK</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
if (isset($_POST['event_id'])) {

  $event_id = $_GET['event_id'];

  header("Location: /wp-admin/admin.php?page=evpl-sessions");
  exit; 
}
```

Но, не совсем понимаю как всё разложить в  `<option name="' . $key . '"> Тут должно быть название и дата мероприятия </option>` , плюс добавить туда ещё дату.

В конечном итоге конечно переменная `$event_id` пустая.

Заранее большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: что-то мне подсказыавет, что костыли с json_decode-encode и последующим циклом сложения в массив, можно просто заменить на `$dayCouwfnts = array_column($event_info, 'title', 'event_id')`

Comment: В таком случае wordpress начинается сыпаться. "последующим циклом сложения в массив" - тоже пока не всё удачно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только у select будет name, а у option будет value="$event_id"

```
<select name="event_id">
<option value="$event_id">$title</option>
</select>
```

А ещё мне очень понравился вот этот кусочек вашего кода:

```
    if (isset($_POST['event_id'])) {
$event_id = $_GET['event_id'];
```

Проверяем POST, а присваиваем GET?

Comment: Это сюда так вписал, на сервере везде POST, дополнительно ещё раз всё проверил )))

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось.